# Change document root after installing web applications

Tags: server, plesk

I ordered a vserver with Plesk, installed Moodle through Plesk and worked some months on it.

The domain for Moodle is `www.urltomyserver.com/moodle`. I would like to change it to just `www.urltomyserver.com`. Thus I would like to change my document root in my hosting settings to `httpdocs/moodle` for this domain. However this does not work:

> Unable to change document root: It is impossible to change document
>   root because there are web applications installed on this website

I know that when I change the document root, I need to make changes to the Moodle `config.php` file. So I understand the warning and I still would like to change the document root. Is this possible? Maybe directly through the shell?

Otherwise the only option that I see and that I would like to prevent is to make an backup from Moodle, de-install the application through Plesk, install Moodle manually and then change the document root.

Is there a way around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [an answer on Plesk Support](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/214526385-Unable-to-change-document-root-It-is-impossible-to-change-document-root-because-there-are-web-applications-installed-on-this-website):

> In order to change the document root, the problematic application should be uninstalled.

It's also mentioned [here](https://talk.plesk.com/threads/how-can-i-change-the-document-root-with-webapplications-installed.331585/) as well.

It should be possible to directly change your `vhost.conf`or document root via shell. I think this would the be easiest solution. Unfortunately I don't have access to any Plesk to provide instructions, but you may [try this](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/advanced-administration-guide-linux/virtual-hosts-configuration/virtual-hosts-and-hosting-types/virtual-host-configuration-files.72064/).

I also found another [*possible solution*](http://www.fabbro.uk/cannot-changing-the-root-folder-in-plesk/) which involves renaming the current domain and adding back the domain. Do remember to make backup of your files and database before attempting this.

And last resort would be the solution you suggested. Good luck!